# Typescript default Generic typings

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I would like to create a pagination wrapper around axios. In this wrapper, I'll be able to transform the data payload, and add multiple other transformers to get the last page, or the total count of items.

And I also need default parameters for very basic usage (payload data = data)

But I'm having trouble typing the default functions if they are not provided

This is what I came up so far:

```ts
type PaginateOptions<T, Payload = T[]> = {
  url: string;
  currentPage?: number;
  resultsPerPage?: number;
  range?: number;
  updateFn: (page?: number) => void;
  options: Ref<Record<string | number, string | number>>;
  dataTransformer: (payload: Payload) => Payload extends T[] ? Payload : T[];
  totalPageTransformer: (payload: Payload) => number;
  totalTransformer: (payload: Payload) => number;
}

// T refers to the data type I'm fetching, and Payload what the Axios payload looks like
export default function usePaginate<T, Payload>({
  url,
  currentPage: page = 1,
  updateFn = () => {},
  options = ref({}),
  // Error here: Type 'Payload' is not assignable to type 'Payload extends T[] ? Payload : T[]'
  dataTransformer = (results) => results,
  totalPageTransformer,
  totalTransformer,
  resultsPerPage = 25,
  range = 5,
}: PaginateOptions<T, Payload>) {
  const data = ref<T[]>([]); // I'm storing the fetched data here
  /* ... */
  return { data };
}
```

Payload example:

```ts
// Basic payload, with separated data and pagination info
axios.get<Payload>(url, options)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    // data is of type Payload
    console.log(data);
    /*
    {
      "data": [{ "name": "A", "id": 1 }, { "name": "B", "id": 2 }, { "name": "B", "id": 3 }],
      "pagination": {
        "total": 15,
        "page": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 3
      }
    }
    */
  });

axios.get<Payload>(url, options)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    // data is of type Payload
    console.log(data);
    /*
    No pagination data, I can provide it locally if I know it is fixed (search by first letter => always 26)
    [{ "name": "A", "id": 1 }, { "name": "B", "id": 2 }, { "name": "B", "id": 3 }]
    */
  });
```

Comment: So `Payload` is the axios response, and T is the data type you want to get out of the function? Like `response.data` is `Payload` and i.e. `Consumer` is `T`?

Comment: Correct. I'll try to provide an example with different payloads and usage

Comment: Does the question depend on axios? If so, consider tagging it as such.  If not, consider editing the code to remove it as a dependency; ideally someone could take your code and drop it into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and demonstrate the issue you're seeing (and only that issue).  Providing a [mcve] goes a long way toward getting a useful answer, since the person answering can actually test the answer they give.  Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I don't think it goes into any of those 2 cases: It is not dependant on Axios, as I don't have any problem on it, type inference is good, but I need to show how I use my payload (explained in my latest edit). The concern here is just the typings of the function parameters with the default parameter if not provided. It already is a minimal reproducible example. The part concerning axios is to explain the context and what's the use.